# How to keep records in an Oracle table based on the nearest date

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c

I have an Oracle table T where there are multiple records with different startdates in them. I would like to delete all but to keep the one with the greatest dates among the same combination of col1,col2,col3. In this example, I want to keep the one with date as 31-May-17 and delete the other two. What would be the best possible way to achieve this in a single query without creating another staging table?

Test scripts -

```
create table t 
(col1 number(10)
,col2 number(10)
,col3 number(10)
,col4 number(10)
,col5 date
);

insert into t values (15731,467,4087,14427,'09-Apr-17');
insert into t values (15731,467,4087,17828,'31-May-17');
insert into t values (15731,467,4087,15499,'16-Apr-17');
commit;

select * from t;[enter image description here][1]
```

Based on the data above, I would like to keep only the record where the date is 31-May-17 since that is the greatest of the dates having same combination of col1,col2,col3 and delete the remaining two off the table. Note that there are millions other records such as above on this table.
Apologize if this is too naive a question for Oracle experts but I am very new trying my hands on in Oracle db at this place.

Comment: How would you tie-break multiple records the same time-distance from now?

Comment: That's exactly what I realized could be a challenge to achieve - whatif the time-displacement is the same? In order to make it simpler, I changed my criteria to delete the older dates having same key of col1,col2 and col3 and to keep the records with the greatest of the dates for that key combo. Thanks for pointing out!!

Comment: Please change your description that it is clear how to hanle ties. Pleas chan the example to illustrate such a case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is tagged **oracle12c**, you might as well take advantage of its features. For example, using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```
delete from t
  where rowid not in (
                       select rowid
                       from   t
                         match_recognize (
                           partition by col1, col2, col3
                           order by col5 desc
                           all rows per match
                           pattern ( ^ a x* )
                           define x as x.col5 = a.col5
                         )
                     )
;
```

This assumes you want to keep all the rows "tied" for latest start-date for a given combination of COL1, COL2, COL3. The solution can be adapted for variations of the requirement.

Comment: Thanks Mathguy...I have been reading about Match_Recognize function from oracle documentation and interesting how they developed the pattern matching criteria....Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You can order the rows by the absolute value of the difference between the date and `sysdate`. You can then use the `rowid` pseudocolumn to correlate between the query and the delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE  rowid NOT IN (SELECT r
                     FROM   (SELECT rowid AS r, 
                                    ROW_NUMBNER() OVER 
                                        (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3
                                         ORDER BY ABS(SYSDATE - col5) ASC) AS rn
                             FROM   t)
                     WHERE  rn = 1)
```

Comment: this should also include a `partition by..` and `RANK` maybe instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: I apologize for not being very clear, but I meant to keep the one with the greatest of the dates among all the dates with the same combination of col1,col2,col3 instead of finding to the nearest date.

Comment: @vkp Given Brendon's last comment, you're right - the `partition by` clause is missing there. Regarding the `row_number` vs `rank` issue - that depends if OP wants to keep a single record or all the tied records

Comment: Thanks Mureinik for the sql - much appreciated!! I am going through oracle documentation to learn the partition by clause and using with row_number. I am getting a syntax error while running your sql though oracle is griping for a missing right parenthesis!! and I am scratching my head where could it go missing from?

Comment: @Brendon - In Comments under the original post, the OP stated that he would prefer to keep all rows tied for "most recent" start date. In that case, `rank()` should be used instead of `row_number()`. If the business requirement changes (for example, in case of a tie, keep only the row with the largest value in COL4), `row_number()` can be used, with the additional ordering criterion added to the `order by` clause in `row_number()`.